# How can I send multiple files from HTML5 file upload input with Ajax to Ruby on Rails without any plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, jquery, file-upload

Here is the code of HTML5:

```
<input class="image_file"  type="file" name="file_image" multiple />
```

Here is the code of Rails:

```
@filename = params[:file_image].original_filename
```

My solution is only for single file. How can I code multiple in rails with ajax or jquery? Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

If you have pro subscription to Railscasts.com you can find a screen casting which does exactly what you require.

If you dont try this jquery fileupload rails gem[1], if you dont want to use gem, use jquery fileupload plugin[2] directly, but I would suggest you to use gem.

[1] https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails
[2] http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload